# Introduction to the mathematical theory of regularization

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, regularization

I asked the question "[Are there books on Regularization at an Introductory level?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12385/are-there-books-on-regularization-at-an-introductory-level)" at physics.SE.

I was informed that "there is (...) a mathematical theory of regularization (Cesàro, Borel, Ramanujan summations and many others) that is interesting per se".

**Question:** Can someone advise me on how to study one or more of the above topics and provide some reference?

Comment: Vladimir Alexandrovich Smirnov's book [Feynman integral calculus](http://books.google.com/books?id=uYW6raeFrCUC) is mentioned in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12235/iterated-dimensional-regularization/12397#12397) Physics.SE answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of summations of otherwise divergent series (which is what [Borel summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation) and [Cesàro summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesaro_summation) are about), a decent reference is G.H. Hardy's [*Divergent Series*](http://www.archive.org/details/divergentseries033523mbp).

In terms of divergent integrals, you may also be interested in learning about [Cauchy principal values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), which is related to [Hadamard regularisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization). (The references in those Wikipedia articles should be good enough; these two concepts are actually quite easily understood.)

[Zeta function regularisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization) has its roots in number theory, which unfortuantely I don't know enough about to comment.

[Heat kernel type regularisation techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization) is closely related to the study of partial differential equations and harmonic analysis. It is related to Friedrichs mollifiers (an exposition is available in most introductory texts in generalised functions / distribution theory; and a slightly more advanced text is volume 1 of Hörmander's *Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operator*). It can also be interpreted as a Fourier-space cut-off (which in physics terminology is probably called "ultraviolet cutoff" and which can be interpreted in physical space as setting a minimal length scale), so can be described in terms of, say, Littlewood-Paley Theory (another advanced text is Stein's *Topics in Harmonic Analysis relating to Littlewood-Paley Theory*) or the [FBI transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBI_transform). Unfortunately I don't know many good introduction texts in these areas. But I hope some of these keywords can aid your search.

Comment: Many thanks for informing on so many areas where regularization techniques appear.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure it is what you're asking but it seems that you're interested in [summability methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summability_theory) and in [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverman%E2%80%93Toeplitz_theorem) matrix methods.

As far as I know, the pioneering work in this area was Hardy's book [Divergent series](http://www.archive.org/details/divergentseries033523mbp). It is mentioned in the wikipedia article, too. [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=jPccoUKsLdQC) is google books preview.

Classical references in this area seem to be:

- Richard G. Cooke: [Infinite matrices and sequence spaces](http://books.google.com/books?id=M3o6AAAAMAAJ) (I only have access to Russian translation Кук Р. - Бесконечные матрицы и пространства последовательностей)
- G. M. Petersen: [Regular matrix transformations](http://books.google.com/books?id=C3KmAAAAIAAJ)

Texts which tend more towards functional analysis (thus they could be called more modern) are:

- J. Boos: [Classical and modern methods in summability](http://books.google.com/books?id=kZ9cy6XyidEC) I have written down some [notes](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/texty/rozne/trf/boos/boos.pdf) while reading a few first chapters. You can see I did not get too far. (There were some typos and minor mistakes, otherwise my impression is that it's a well-organized and interesting book.)
- A. Wilansky: [Summability Through Functional Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=vKAMMYuWAAAC)

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed information!

Comment: There is "infinite sequences and series" by Konrad Knopp; I found it a bit easier to read than Hardy's book. Also it is possibly better designed for the self-study because its writing style is a bit more pedagogic and it contains exercises at each chapter.